# Google Recaptcha V2 response error

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google Recaptcha V2 using Server side code implementation.Now when i am trying to send `g-recaptcha-response` i am getting an error like `ReferenceError: g is not defineddata: JSON.stringify(g-recaptcha-response),` and when i am not sending this parameter i am getting `Not defined error` on server side code.Here is my Client side Code using AJAX..

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#Captcha').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:64132/ValidateCaptcha',
                data: JSON.stringify(g-recaptcha-response),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',  // Set response datatype as JSON
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data = true) {
                        $("#lblmsg").text("Validation Success!!");
                    } else {

                        $("#lblmsg").text("Oops!! Validation Failed!! Please Try Again");
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

Please help me to resolve and implement the same.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(g-recaptcha-response),` i don't see where you defined it? `-->g-recaptcha-response`

Comment: JavaScript variable cannot contain `-` sign. Where does this `g-recaptcha-response` come from?

Comment: @Jai It Should be returned by the Google recaptcha API

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev It is coming from Google recaptcha API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) how to verify `g-recaptcha-responce`. Actually it's text-area field, so in jquery you might address it as $('#g-recaptcha-response').val()

So on client side:

```
var response = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:64132/ValidateCaptcha',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { response: response },
            ...
```

See my [post](http://scraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/) on it.

### Some more

Seems to me that you do a tricky thing:
Immediate on reCaptcha click you make a xhr (jquery ajax request):

`$('#Captcha').click(function () {
            $.ajax({...})`

Yet, google api might has not yet evaluated the bot-human cues and has not returned response. Therefore no `g-recaptcha-response` is present on a client side when you invoke xhr!

Better you wait (timeout) untill `$('#g-recaptcha-response').val() <> ''` and then you make xhr to veryfy site.